# How to bind decorated command handler classes with Ninject

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ninject, cqrs

I have a command handler **interface** type,

```
public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}
```

**implemented** command handlers are executing by command dispatched object.

```
public class CommandDispacher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly IServiceLocator serviceLocator;

    public CommandDispacher(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        this.serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    public void Dispatch<TCommand>(ICommand command)
    {
        var commandType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
        var handler = serviceLocator.Resolve(commandType);

        ((dynamic)handler).Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}
```

I am binding the command handler classes by ninject like this:

```
           Kernel.Bind(scanner =>     
           scanner.FromAssembliesMatching("*")
           .IncludingNonePublicTypes()
           .SelectAllClasses()
           .InheritedFrom(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
           .BindSingleInterface());
```

This works.

But I need command handler decorators, for example validations:

```
public class PostCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<T> : ICommandHandler<T> where T:ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<T> decorated;
    private readonly PostCommitRegistratorImpl registrator;

    public PostCommitCommandHandlerDecorator(ICommandHandler<T> decorated, PostCommitRegistratorImpl registrator)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
        this.registrator = registrator;
    }

    public void Handle(T command)
    {
        try
        {
            decorated.Handle(command);

            registrator.ExecuteActions();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            registrator.Reset();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I decorate my command handler classes with decorators with this like?
Should I bind it to Ninject kernel? Because my commands are executed by **ICommandDispatches** object.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box Ninject does not support a decorator configuration.

However, you can use [contextual bindings](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) to achieve decoration:

```
Bind(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
  .To(typeof(PostCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<>));

Bind(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
  .To(typeof(CommandHandler<>))
  .When(request =>
     request.Target.Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
     == typeof(PostCommitCommandHandlerDecorator<>));
```

Instead of the `.When(..)` overload `.WhenInjectedInto(typeof(PostCommitCOmmandHandlerDecorator<>))` might work as well, but i suspect it won't.

Comment: What namespace is the CommandHandler object in?

Comment: it's code you write yourself, so whereever you place it.